# Firefox: pass event from anonymous javascript function

Tags: anonymous-function, event-handling, event-passthrough

In this abbreviated code, the inline event works - the "event" is passed to the testKeyPress function

```
<textarea id="source"
    onkeydown= "showCursPos(this); 
    var tf=testKeyPress(event);
    document.onkeypress=function(){return tf};
    document.onkeydown=function(){return tf}; " ></textarea>

function testKeyPress(e){
    if (e.ctrlKey==true ){
        if (e.which == null ){kcode=e.keyCode; }  // IE
        else if (e.which > 0){kcode=e.which; }    // gecko
        return testValidity(kcode);   //returns true-false
    }
}
```

However, in this anonymous version, the event is not passed in gecko:

```
<textarea id="source"></textarea>

$("source").onkeydown = function(){ 
    showCursPos(this);  // this function works
    // next event is passed in IE, but not gecko
    var tf=testKeyPress(event); 
    // remaining functions work if value is forced
    document.onkeypress=function(){return tf}; 
    document.onkeydown=function(){return tf}; 
    }
```

How does one pass the function's own event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is an event object as arguments.

You can get it by

```
var e=arguments[0] || event; // Firefox via the argument, but IE don't
```

I don't know if they exact the same, but I read `<xxx onkeydown="func(event);">` as `xxx.ononkeydown=function(event){func(event);};`

Reference [event @ Mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Event)

Answer (score 0):

Worked like a charm. This modification to my original code successfully passes the event from the anonymous function to the named function in my four browsers: IE6, FF2, NS7.2, OP9.22

```
$("source").onkeydown = function(){ 
    var e=arguments[0] || event; 
    showCursPos(this);  
    var tf=testKeyPress(e); 
    document.onkeypress=function(){return tf}; 
    document.onkeydown=function(){return tf}; 
}
```